# what is advantage of passing variable over thread messages

Tags: thread-safety

I have doubt over the thread safety

Suppose we have n number of threads, a variable is declared in some thread.. If that variable have to be used by another thread, we have 2 methods

1. Variable can be declared as global in some thread and accessed using extern in another thread
2. Through messages we can pass that variable..

While using 1st option we have issue of variable getting corrupted.. Exactly i dont know how it get corrupted.. Any test case ?

Regards
Vijay

Comment: Google "race condition". This is totally basic stuff, man.